# Python: Create Sql raw query with In clause with list data

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, rawsql

Recently I stuck for a moment while preparing the raw Sql Query having `In clause` to it and the `In clause` data is a `python list`.
Okay Let me put my example here.

Sql Query that I wanted

```
sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE first_name IN ("Dean");'
```

From the data I was having

```
data = ["Dean"]
query = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE first_name IN %s;' % str(tuple(data))
# result was "SELECT * FROM student WHERE first_name IN ('Dean',) "
# see the *Comma* just before close parentheses which is a Sql error
```

But After doing some practice I came up with a solution of something like this

```
str_data = ','.join(repr(x) for x in data)
query = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE first_name IN (%s);' % str_data

# Gives proper result i.e "SELECT * FROM student WHERE first_name IN ('Dean');"
```

Now my question is, is this a elegant solution or we have several other optimized approaches out there in python. Would be appreciable to have your views on this :).

**Edit**
*Reached to another solution*

```
data = tuple(data) if len(data) > 1 else "('%s')" % data[0] # Assumption: data  should not be empty (in my case it is true)
query = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE first_name IN {};'.format(data)
```

**Note:** Still looking for some views from you guys if it can be optimized further.

Comment: What database? What client library? Also, doing anything besides a parametrized query (like the string formatting you use above) for data that could potentially come from the user carries an enormous risk of making you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Its DB2 and we are using SqlAlchemy as toolkit. And here data is having set of unique varchar that we are being taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in python3 on a postgres database, specifically if you want strings
after the IN operator. please pay attention to the double quotes vs single quotes:

```
data = ['test', 'test2', 'test3']
data_str = "', '".join(data)
query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE first_name IN ('{}');".format(data_str))
```

or like this if you prefer f-strings:

```
print(f"SELECT * FROM student WHERE first_name IN ('{data_str}');")
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you emphasized the importance of preventing SQL injection. Safeguarding against such vulnerabilities is highly important. If you have a method for dynamically managing multiple values for the IN expression and protecting against SQL injection, that method is indeed good.

```
    data = ['test', 'test2', 'test3']
    data_str = {','.join(['%s'] * len(data))}
    query = f"SELECT * FROM student WHERE first_name IN ({data_str});"
    ...
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query, data)
    ...
```