# Django raw SQL query error 1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I'm trying to count the results of a raw SQL query using the following code:

```
len(tuple(passwords.raw('SELECT classifyID FROM djangomysqldb.password_classify WHERE pw IN (%s)', [list])))
```

I have read on stack overflow that this is an effective method, however it results in the following error:

(1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')

Why do I get this error when this method seems to work for other users?

Comment: "I have read on stack overflow that this is an effective method" where? A `COUNT` query would be far more efficient. This question is tagged with Django, is there a reason you are not using the ORM?

Comment: I am not using the ORM for this query because the MySQL character set results in case insensitivity for this query, but I need it to be case sensitive. I am performing a raw query so I can use custom collation to perform the query in a case sensitive manner (I omitted this code because I thought it was not relevant - I get the same error with or without it).
Here is an example where a user suggests this method: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443867/python-create-sql-raw-query-with-in-clause-with-list-data

Comment: The best solution for you would be to use a sensible character set for your MySQL tables, then you wouldn't have to write raw queries